# Why does my nodejs function always return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I've defined 2 functions and calling one function from another. The result is always null

```
var abc = (req,callBack) => {
DB Operation
.
.
.
.
console.log(result);
callBack(null,result);
}


var def = (req, callBack) => {
abc(req,(response) => {
   callBack(null,result);
});
}
```

the console.log prints actual result but the callBack from function def always returns null. What is that I'm missing here.

Comment: What you provided is not real code. It's impossible to help you with JS when what you posted is not JS.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to provide the community with the information required to give you helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to add error in the function.

```
var abc = (req,callBack) => {
DB Operation
.
.
.
.
console.log(result);
callBack(null,result);
}


var def = (req, callBack) => {
abc(req,(err, response) => {
if(err){
  callBack({
             error:'Oops Something went wrong'
});
}else{
  callBack(null,result);
}

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **callback** function should have the correct number of parameter.
Thus, if you have **callback(parameter1, parameter2)** then you should receive the result like **function(parameter1, parameter2)**

```
function foo(callback) {
    **DB operation 
    callback(err, response);
}

function bar() {
    foo(function(err, response) {
       // do stuff here
    })
}
```

Another thing, you can check if your **callback** is a function or not before you call them.

```
if (typeof callback === "function")
```